# Play framework show States list from DB based on selected Country Id using AJAX

Tags: ajax, scala, playframework-2.3

I am a newbie to Play Framework with Scala. Currently in my project's registration `form` I have options of `Country` and `States` in `Drop down`. I need to show the States `list` for the selected `Country`. Using an AJAX call for this purpose I have used the below code snippet. But it shows

```
Cannot write an instance of Seq[(String, String)] to HTTP response. 
Try to define a Writeable[Seq[(String, String)]]
```

**What I tried**

**addStudent.scala.html**

```
  <div>
    Country:
      @select(
        studentForm("country"),
        countryList,
        '_default -> "-- Choose Country --",
        'onChange->"ajaxCallforStateList(this.value)")      
  </div>

  <script>
    function ajaxCallforStateList(countyid) {
        ajaxCall(countyid);
        var testAjax = jsRoutes.controllers.Students.ajaxCall(countyid);

        $.ajax({
            url : testAjax.url
        });
    }

    var ajaxSuccess = function(action, data) {
        $("body").append("<br/>");
        $("body").append(action + " " + data);
    };

    var ajaxError = function(action, error) {
        alert(action + " : " +error);
    }

    function ajaxCall(countyid) {
        var ajaxCallBack = {
            success : onSuccess,
            error : onError
        }
        jsRoutes.controllers.Students.ajaxCall(countyid).ajax(ajaxCallBack);
    };

    var onSuccess = function(data) {        
        alert(data);
    }

    var onError = function(error) { 
        alert(error);
    }
  </script>
```

**JavascriptRoute.scala**

```
package controllers

import play.api.Routes
import play.api.mvc.Action
import play.api.mvc.Controller
import play.api.mvc.EssentialAction
import play.core.Router.JavascriptReverseRoute
import play.core.Router._
import routes.javascript.Application.index
import routes.javascript.Students.ajaxCall

object JavascriptRoute extends Controller {

  /* Application related JavascriptReverse Route will goes here */
  val appRoutes: List[JavascriptReverseRoute] = List(index, ajaxCall)

  /* All JavascriptReverse Route will combine here */
  val javascriptRouters = appRoutes

  /**
   * This is use to generate JavascriptReverseRoute for all provided actions
   *
   * @return
   */
  def javascriptRoutes: EssentialAction = Action { implicit request =>
    import routes.javascript._
    Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(javascriptRouters: _*)).as("text/javascript")
  }

}
```

**routes**

```
GET    /ajax-call/:countryId         controllers.Students.ajaxCall(countryId:String)

#Javascript Routes
GET    /javascriptRoutes            controllers.JavascriptRoute.javascriptRoutes
```

**Students.scala**

```
 def ajaxCall(countryId:String) = Action { implicit request =>     
   Ok(stateList.options(countryId))          
}
```

**Student.scala**

```
case class stateList(stateid:Option[Int] = None,
                      statename: String)

object stateList{

  val simple = {
    get[Option[Int]]("state.STATE_ID") ~
    get[String]("state.STATE") map {
      case stateid~statename => stateList(stateid,statename)
    }
  }

  def options(countryId:String): Seq[(String,String)] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
 SQL("select * from state WHERE COUNTRY_ID = {countryid}")
 .on('countryid->countryId)
 . as(stateList.simple *).      
      foldLeft[Seq[(String, String)]](Nil) { (cs, c) => 
        c.stateid.fold(cs) { id => cs :+ (id.toString-> c.statename) }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to indicate from where the error comes exactly

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to render a `Seq[(String,String)]` (from `stateList.options(countryId)`) as the body of an Action, but you haven't told Play how to serialize it. You could define a `Writeable` (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.http.Writeable) to tell Play how to convert your Seq into something your client will know how to read. Presumably you're looking for a simple string, so either your Writeable wants to be a very simple conversion, or you could even change `Ok(stateList.options(countryId))` to be `Ok(stateList.options(countryId).mkString("[",",","]"))`.

Comment: could you please provide any example for this?

Comment: I use `Ok(stateList.options(countryId).mkString("[",",","]"))` this code,It shows `StateList:=[(1,tamilnadu),(2,kerala)]` in `onSuccess` methods alert.
How may I convert this `String` into `Seq[(String, String)]` for showing values in `Drop Down`

Comment: You don't. You've now got an object to parse in your javascript. It's not one that's terribly friendly to parse though. Consider using Json as mentioned in the other answer (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson for the docs).

Once you've parsed your response, you need to set the values in your select box.

Comment: I used that `JsArray` option which mentioned by `John` it shows `Int does not take parameters`

Comment: Clive Evans could you please tell me how to set the result as `JSON` and how to parse the `JSON` string as `Seq[String,String]`

Answer (score 0):

According to your existing code and if I understood the question correctly, a quick way to output a JSON would be

```
OK(JsArray(stateList.options(countryId).map{case (id, name) =>
  JsObject(Seq(
    "id"   -> JsString(x.id),
    "name" -> JsString(x.name)
  ))
}))
```

Comment: I added the `above` code snippet but it shows 
`Int does not take parameters` error